# Sorting table row using jQuery/JavaScript

Tags: jquery

I want to sort table row based on status of device.I need to sort onLine devices first  and second i need to show offline device in table row.

I have below table in UI.

```
Device status
Mac1    Offline
Mac2    Online
Mac3    Online   

<table id="webPaDeviceTable" class="table table-bordered">
  <thead>
  <tr class="info">
    <th style="width: 10px;">SA</th>
    <th>Device</th>
    <th> Status</th>

  </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody class="parameter_table">
    <% @my_devices.all.each do |parameter| %>

    <tr id="tr_device_<%=parameter.id %>">

      <td id="macAddress" style="word-break:break-all;">
       <%= parameter.mac_address%> 
      </td>

      <td class="Selected_Device" id="Selected_Device">
      <b id="Selected_Device" style="float: right; color: orange;">loading..</b>

     </td>
    </tr>
    <% end %>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: For starters you need unique IDs. and then google jquery table sort

Comment: jquery datatables (https://datatables.net)

Answer (score 0):

You can use jquery-bootgrid (http://www.jquery-bootgrid.com/)

Add `data-column-id` to your grid and `data-order` to your `th` for example

```
<th data-column-id="received" data-order="desc">Received</th>
```

An example at http://www.jquery-bootgrid.com/examples

After that a simple call to `$("#webPaDeviceTable").bootgrid();` will convert your table to sort able grid.